# Choosing a margin for contrastive loss in a siamese network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, computer-vision, pytorch

I'm building a siamese network for a metric-learning task, using a contrastive loss function, and I'm uncertain on how to set the 'margin' hyperparameter for the loss.

My inputs to the loss function are currently 1024-dimension dense embeddings from an RNN layer - Does the dimensionality of that input affect how I pick a margin? Should I use a dense layer to project it to a lower-dimensional space first? Any pointers on how to pick a specific margin value (or any relevant research) would be really appreciated! In case it matters, I'm using PyTorch.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to project it to a lower dimensional space. 
The dependence of the margin with the dimensionality of the space depends on how the loss is formulated: If you don't normalize the embedding values and compute a global difference between vectors, the right margin will depend on the dimensionality. But if you compute a normalize difference, such as cosine distance, the margin values won't depend on the dimensionality of the embedding space.
Here ranking (or contrastive) losses are explained, it might be useful https://gombru.github.io/2019/04/03/ranking_loss/